# R- qplot not changing colors properly

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I wanted to start by saying that I've perused the other questions here including the one at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882206/qplot-changing-the-color-of-my-histograms). I tried pretty much copy/pasting the examples there but I'm still having the issue. I am also pretty new to R in general

FWIW I'm using R studio on ubuntu 13.10 to do this. I have a vector of values 1:8773 or so of square footages of buildings. When I try

```
qplot(sqFootage, geom = "histogram", colour = "red")
```

I get this picture :.

[image]

Clearly that's not red; it does the same thing for other colors (green, dark green, dodgerblue, firebrickred4) and I'm not sure why.

I've imported the `ggplot2` library (or else it wouldn't even show up I guess). Any advice?

Comment: `colour=I("red")`, to bypass the aesthetic mapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `colour` with `fill`:

```
qplot(sqFootage, geom = "histogram", fill = I("red"))
```

The parameter `colour` is used to define the colours of the borders of the rectangles.

Furthermore, you have to use the `I` function. Otherwise, `"red"` is interpreted as a factor (as Ben Bolker points out).

Comment: I think this isn't quite right.  In `qplot` (*not* in `ggplot()`), `fill="red"` creates a one-element factor with level `"red"`; it's a coincidence that ggplot's default colour for a single-level factor is reddish. if you actually want the colour, or fill, to be red, you **must** use `I("red")`.  (For an illustration, try `fill="blue"` and see what happens ...)

Comment: @BenBolker I modified the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!